# how to create a custom sort in JavaScript datable

Tags: javascript, jquery

i stucked in sorting a column which shows the duration of the error i have attached you a screenshot of what im saying, data table is very weird in those things  :

```
 <table width="100%" data-bind="dataTable: {
        dataSource: filteredErrorTurbines,
        options: { 
            bFilter: false,
            bPaginate: false,
            bInfo: false,
            aoColumnDefs: [{
           mDataProp: function ( source, type, val ) {
                    
              var x=source.StatusMessage.m_status_active_since_min();    
               d = Math.floor(source.StatusMessage.m_status_active_since_min()/1440); //Month
               h = Math.floor((source.StatusMessage.m_status_active_since_min()-(d*1440))/60);//Days
               m = Math.round(source.StatusMessage.m_status_active_since_min()%60)//Minutes

                  if(d>0){
                        return(d + ' days, ' + h + ' hours, '+m+' minutes');
                      }
                  if(h>0){
                        return(h + ' hours, '+m+' minutes');
                         }
                            else{
                        return(m+' minutes');
                            }                       
                     },
                aTargets: [1],
                bSortable: true,
                sWidth: '18em'
            },{
                mDataProp: 'Name',
                aTargets: [2]
            },{
                mDataProp: 'StatusMessage.WindSpeed',
                aTargets: [3],
                sWidth: '8em'
            },{
                mDataProp: 'StatusMessage.Power',
                aTargets: [4],
                sWidth: '5em'
            },{
                mDataProp: 'StatusMessage.RPM',
                aTargets: [5],
                sWidth: '4em'
            }
        }
</table>
```

The first column is the one should be sorted i have added the screenshot[image: theColumnshouldBeSorted] here :

as you can see in the function calculates the month,day,minute from the valuesi get from the database,the values i get are like 16.5607333333333,so the function extract the date from it

Comment: What type of data goes into that first column?

Comment: i get a raw number which i have to extract day,hour and minute out of it ,as you can see in the screenshot

Comment: Can you add a sample of the data to your question? Could it be it's a string and not a number?

Comment: @Icepickle i have updated my code and question

Comment: It still doesn't answer my question completely, I want to see raw data, you state that it is a number, but if it would be a number then it should be the correct value. What would happen if you would add the exact dataset here (for the error duration only?)

Comment: @Icepickle im asked to show the data like this,if i show the numbers like the sample i gave you,it can be sorted easily since they are numbers,but when i change to this format ,sorting is the problem,all numbers i get is in minutes from the server,like 309500.485966667 which i should convert it to month day and minutes to show it